# Getting the n-th child which also matches a compound selector in each row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, children, css-selectors

Say I have the following markup

```
<div><p></p><blockquote></blockquote><ul>...</ul></div>
<div><p></p><blockquote></blockquote><ul>...</ul></div>
 ...
<div><p></p><blockquote></blockquote><ul>...</ul><ul></ul></div>
```

Is there a jQuery selector/traversal technique I can use to get the nth child matching a complex selector in each div which is robust (in the sense that I can change elements not matched by the selector without messing things up)

Here are some approaches that don't work to help illustrate the problem

```
 $("div").children("p, ul").filter(":eq(1)") // returns just the first <ul> in the first div
 $("div").children("p, ul:eq(1)") // returns all the p's and the first ul in the first div
 $("div").find(":not(blockquote):eq(1)") //returns the correct elements, but at the expense of having to reference the elements we're *not* after. Also not restricted to just children
 $("div").find(">:not(blockquote):eq(1)") ) // tackles the children problem, but ">" without a parent is not officially supported and jQuery want to deprecate (Can't find the reference but I raised it once in discussion on the jQuery bug boards and John Resig himself said this)
```

Finally for some context, I'm asking this in order to always find the ith column of a table regardless of whether or not the first column contains `th` or `td` cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about it I realised what's needed is some sort of `:is()` selector to wrap the compound selector. jQuery won't implement it ([for good reasons](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11299)), but then I realised a double negative is the same as a positive so the following works for the general case

```
$("div").find(">:not(:not(p, ul)):eq(1)")
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes jQuery has a `nth-child selector`

[jQuery - :nth-child() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Cheers

Comment: Ah... but thinking about it it still doesn't quite work for the general case (although solves my table column problem perfectly :) ) because we're not looking for the nth-child of a parent, we're looking for the nth child element that matches a selector, which is not quite the same. I was making a jsfiddle to demonstrate but the site's being buggy, but essentially if the first few elements don't match the selector then nth-child won't point to the n-th matching child, it'll still point to the nth child (I think... that's what I was trying to jsfiddle to test out)

Comment: @wheresrhys I don't not really understand. Your fiddle does not work because `eq` is zero based and `nth-child` is not. http://jsfiddle.net/2YXLq/1/

Comment: I was expecting the second line to fail because I was trying to demonstrate that finding children matching a selector and then returning the nth one of them (hopefully what I asked in my question, though it's a subtle thing to describe so maybe I could describe it better), is different to returning the nth child if it matches the selector (which, I think, is the closest to a solution you can get using :nth-child)